# SBT Allow duplicates during assembly

Tags: assembly, sbt, deduplication

`enter code here`Is there a way to turn off reduplication in *SBT's* `assembly` plugin?

I've been cleaning out an `sbt assembly` build the old fashioned way, using `sbt dependency-graph` to remove jar files which have differing versions of the same file.

- if I simply use *last* for the strategy, the resulting jar file failst with a duplicate entry when running makeJar.
- if I use *discard* for the strategy, the resulting jar file is trivial, with nothing in it.

However, in my case, this isn't a huge problem  : I'd like to simply avoid doing reduplication entirely, and later at *run time* if I have issues, clean up dependency conflicts.  This is normally how tools like **maven** seem to work, and I'd like to use SBT to build jars which are similar to the fat jars which are built by those tools.

Comment: Note : I've successfully found a way to solve this by using ```mergeStrategy in assembly := {MergeStrategy.discard... ```  in by build.sbt file.  not sure if that is a good solution or not though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a *reasonable* merge strategy, it looks like this, taken from https://github.com/moser/foxtrot_mike_client/blob/master/build.sbt.

```
mergeStrategy in assembly := { 
  case n if n.startsWith("META-INF/eclipse.inf") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case n if n.startsWith("META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case n if n.startsWith("META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case n if n.startsWith("META-INF/ECLIPSEF.SF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case n if n.startsWith("META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case n if n.startsWith("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case n if n.startsWith("META-INF/NOTICE.txt") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case n if n.startsWith("META-INF/NOTICE") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case n if n.startsWith("META-INF/LICENSE.txt") =>     
 MergeStrategy.discard
      case n if n.startsWith("META-INF/LICENSE") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case n if n.startsWith("rootdoc.txt") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case n if n.startsWith("readme.html") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case n if n.startsWith("readme.txt") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case n if n.startsWith("library.properties") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case n if n.startsWith("license.html") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case n if n.startsWith("about.html") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case _ => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
    }
```

The answer to the original question, is simply, that you have to define a MergeStrategy when using sbt assembly, and there are plenty of templates (like this one) which you can borrow and paste into your *build.sbt* file.